# Infinite loop outside of the loop() function

Tags: c++, loops, arduino, nodemcu, arduino-esp8266

This is the pseudo code of my Arduino sketch for NodeMCU. It has an handler that updates the LED strip continuously.

```
void setup() {

}

void loop() {

}

bool handler() {
//intended infinite loop
}
```

The problem is that the infinite loop is blocking the main `loop()`. Is there a way that I can execute the infinite loop without blocking the main `loop()` function.

I am sorry my question is vague, I am only a beginner in Arduino programming.

Comment: Use break .. to come out of the loop

Comment: Why not just not use a loop, and make it a handler you call regularly from the main loop?

Comment: I think I get what you guys are saying. I will check tonight and reply back. Thank you all.

Answer (score 2):

You should have only one "infinite" loop in your sketch, and it's already constructed for you, it's `loop()`.  Every other loop -- or any function call, for that matter -- that you construct **must** have some way to exit and get back to `loop()`, preferably quickly.  You could exit with a `break` or any other mechanism that returns control to `loop()`.  But you must return...

Answer (score 1):

dont block the main loop instead let the loop to call the handler every time the function is called...

```
void setup()
{
    //setup required parameters/handlers
}

void loop()
{
    // a piece of code that calls the handler
    if(handler())
    {
        // TODDY
    }
}

bool handler()
{
    //intended infinite loop
}
```